# getSupportMenuInflater or getMenuInflate method does not get recognized

Tags: android

I have ListFragment and getSupportMenuInflater() method is not recognized.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.welcome, menu);
    return true;
    }
```

what do i need to define?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a Fragment, you should get the Activity and apply `getMenuInflater()` to it.

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.welcome, menu);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
getSherlockActivity().getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.welcome, menu);
```

Looks like `getSherlockActivity` is just a shortcut to:

```
(SherlockActivity) getActivity()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().inflate(R.menu.welcome, menu);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: You probably mean `getSherlockActivity.getSupportMenuInflater()` instead of `getSherlockActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()`?